# Solving a nonlinear 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I need help solving this nonlinear first order ODE. Any help will be appreciated.

$y'(x) + ay(x) + \frac{bx^2}{y(x)} + cx + d = 0$

Thank you.

Comment: For a particular initial condition? For particular values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ (which are constant, right?)?

Comment: No particular initial condition and yes a,b,c,d are constants.

Comment: I don't think that you can find a closed solution for any $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. If $c=d=0$, one can find a solution.

Comment: @user37238 thank you for the suggestion, I do know about that special case but I want a general case if possible. I'm hoping some sort of substitution or unknown method to me, will help me out..

Comment: One way to find a solution (in the general case where $c$ and $d$ are a priori nonzero) is to use power series. Do you know anything about power series (and specially their applications to differential equations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$y'(x)+ay(x)+\dfrac{bx^2}{y(x)}+cx+d=0$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-ay^2-(cx+d)y-bx^2$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $y=e^{-ax}u$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{-ax}\dfrac{du}{dx}-ae^{-ax}u$

$\therefore e^{-ax}u\left(e^{-ax}\dfrac{du}{dx}-ae^{-ax}u\right)=-ae^{-2ax}u^2-(cx+d)e^{-ax}u-bx^2$

$e^{-2ax}u\dfrac{du}{dx}-ae^{-2ax}u^2=-ae^{-2ax}u^2-(cx+d)e^{-ax}u-bx^2$

$e^{-2ax}u\dfrac{du}{dx}=-(cx+d)e^{-ax}u-bx^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=-(cx+d)e^{ax}u-bx^2e^{2ax}$